# « Autant pour moi » ou « Au temps pour moi » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Alors que les deux expressions *Autant pour moi* et *Au temps pour moi* sont correctes, beaucoup de personnes utilisent exclusivement la première.

Quelle est la différence de sens entre elles et dans quel cas doit-on utiliser l'une ou l'autre ?

Comment: Je sais que c'est un classique, mais bon, [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_temps_pour_moi) présente ça bien.

Comment: Le blog Amour de la langue française (que j'ai découvert [grâce à vous](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/205/interesting-blogs-about-french-language)) vient récemment de publier un [billet à ce sujet](http://amourdelalanguefrancaise.blogspirit.com/archive/2011/09/16/au-temps-ou-autant.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Only “**au temps pour moi**” is *accepted* by the French academy.

[This very interesting page](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article14) provides more information about it.

> Pour *Le Français correct* de Maurice Grevisse et *Le Petit Robert*, la bonne graphie est « au temps pour moi ». L’origine avancée est militaire (« temps » successifs de maniement d’arme, voir l’expression au temps pour les crosses [de fusil]).
>
> L’expression est utilisée par celui qui, investi de l’autorité (quelle qu’en soit la nature), vient de faire commettre une fausse manoeuvre collective et, par extension, par celui qui s’est trompé et s’en rend compte avant les autres.

I've been often *corrected* when I used the “*autant pour moi* ” version, so I only use “*au temps pour moi* ” now.

Since it's somewhat “official”, it's somewhat “better”.

Comment: +1 pour avoir dit que la phrase "autant pour moi" n'est pas _acceptée_, sans pour autant avoir dit qu'elle est _incorrecte_ :)

Comment: Il y a des gens qui écrivent (pour plaisanter) « au taon pour moi » ou « OTAN pour moi », ce qui met tout le monde (pas) d'accord.

Answer (score 16):

L'expression correcte est « au temps pour moi », qui viendrait du monde militaire. Lorsqu'un soldat sortait du rang (ou se désynchronisait de la marche), on lui disait : « Au temps pour toi », indiquant qu'il devait se recaler sur le temps de la marche.

L'Académie française accepte l'utilisation de « autant pour moi », qui est soutenue par plusieurs grammairiens, comme signifiant : « de même pour moi ».

Dans les deux cas, l'expression indique que l'on s'est trompé en affirmant quelque chose. La variante « au temps » exprime que l'on accepte de rentrer dans le rang, alors que la variante « autant » peut exprimer l'idée que l'erreur qu'on a attribuée à une personne est en fait la nôtre.

Answer (score 16):

Je me rends compte que les réponses qui ont été fournies oublient une importante précision.

> *Maurice :* Combien en voulez-vous ?
>   *Marcel :* J'en prends quatre.
>   *Bebert :* Autant pour moi.

Ici, « *autant* pour moi » est l'unique forme acceptable, sa signification étant « la même quantité pour moi » ou « pareil pour moi », et il n'y a pas débat là-dessus.

Ensuite, lorsqu'il s'agit de la reconnaissance d'une erreur, en effet « *au temps pour moi* » est l'unique forme [reconnue](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#16_strong-em-au-temps-pour-moi-em-strong) par l’académie, et je ne doute pas que l'origine (si ce n'est l'influence) militaire soit (au moins partiellement) fondée.

Cela dit, je suis en complet désaccord lorsqu'elle affirme que « rien ne justifie la graphie *autant pour moi* ». Ma première interprétation aurait été « je reconnais sans concession que je me suis trompé, oui… *autant* pour moi », ce qui revient à dire « je reprends toutes ces corrections à mon compte ». On peut aussi penser à l'interprétation « *autant* pour ma pomme » ; l’académie oserait-elle rectifier cette orthographe ? Mais il y en a bien sûr plein d'autres qui ont déjà été citées — je recommande une fois de plus la lecture de l'[article de langue-fr.net](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article14) à ce sujet — et c'est, je pense, faire preuve de déni que de simplement les ignorer.

Comment: J'approuve complètement :)

Comment: Un [auteur](https://books.google.com/books?id=QoEtSO3TxNMC&pg=PA120&dq=%22au+temps+pour+moi%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2_JnU1u7JAhXEdR4KHdkGCuEQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22au%20temps%20pour%20moi%22&f=false) affirme qu'on peut dorénavant trancher vu les _corpus_. Je ne sais pas. Si on active _case-insensitive_ au _ngram_ on le voit (_au temps_) apparaître (avec une fréquence plus faible que _autant_). Sur _OpenLexique_ dans _films_ j'ai trouvé à première vue au moins deux foix plus de résultats avec _autant_ que _au temps_. Y a-t-il une nouvelle tendance ?

Answer (score 14):

D'après le Larousse des difficultés de la langue française, on utilise exclusivement *au temps* : « Malgré certaines hésitations, le commandement usité à la caserne, dans les salles de gymnastique, etc., pour faire recommencer un mouvement doit s'orthographier *au temps !* » On utilise cette expression après s'être trompé, il s'agit donc bien de recommencer quelque chose.

À mon sens, l'utilisation de *autant* est un défaut d'usage, rentré par erreur dans le langage courant.

Le Larousse précise que l'italien possède l'expression équivalente, à savoir *al tempo !*.

Comment: (+1) Merci également pour l'équivalent italien. Rapprochement pertinent et utile.

Answer (score 8):

[D'après](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#16_strong-em-au-temps-pour-moi-em-strong) l'académie française, il n'y a aucune justification pour l'orthographe *autant pour moi* qui est sûrement une déformation de la première.
*Au temps pour moi* aurait une origine militaire où l'expression « au temps ! » s'utilise pour indiquer la reprise d'un mouvement (cadencé sûrement) depuis le début.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a des écrits qui datent d'avant la prétendue apparition de l'expression "au temps pour moi" associée aux exercices militaires. En effet des écrits montrent l'utilisation du terme "autant pour le brodeur", c'est pour cette raison que certains grammairiens réfutent la version "au temps pour moi".  À mon avis la situation se justifie par le fait que les militaires propagent plus facilement les écrits que les livres (à l'époque), il suffit d'une personne qui se trompe pour propager l'erreur (surtout quand la personne est influente).